# SQL Join - two foreign keys in the same table reference a primary key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables, one is a product transforming history table and the other is the products table:

dbo.Product_Change_History

```
Date  FK_ProductID FK_FinalProductID ChangedBy
20160709    1               3           John
```

dbo.Product_Detail

```
PK_ProductID ProductName 
     1        Red Bike
     3        Green Bike
```

I would like a table like:

```
 Date      ProductName FinalProductName
20160709   Red Bike     Green Bike
```

How do I join the two tables to achieve this?
edit: This is in TSQL

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to join twice, which means you to alias at least one of the joins:

```
SELECT Date, foo.ProductName, bar.FinalProductName
FROM Product_Change_history
LEFT JOIN Product_Detail AS foo ON fk_productid = foo.pk_productid
LEFT JOIN Product_Detail AS bar ON fk_finalproductid = bar.pk_productid
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your help - can you please use the same aliases as I have in my questions - you have used pk_finalproductid and I would not have this for example

Comment: @WillD : you didn't have any aliases in your question. You didn't even have any query at all...

Comment: I really appreciate the answer but to be fair you have turned this into a negative comment for no reason - your answer does not use the same column headers as my question or the same table names. I cannot work out where you have got pk_finalproductid from as I do not have this equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about LEFT joins VS INNER. I would think this would work well.

```
SELECT
 link.Date,
 old.ProductName,
 new.ProductName as FinalProductName
FROM
 dbo.Product_Detail as old
 INNER JOIN dbo.Product_Change_History as link
  ON old.PK_ProductID = link.FK_ProductID
 INNER JOIN dbo.Product_Detail as new
  ON new.PK_ProductID = link.FK_FinalProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ProdChange table(ProductID int, FK_ProductID INT, FK_FinalProductID INT, ChangedBy Varchar(100))

declare @Prod table(ProductID int, ProductName Varchar(100))

insert into @Prod Values(1,'Red Bike')
insert into @Prod Values(3,'Green Bike')

insert into @ProdChange Values(1,1,3,'John')
select * from @Prod
select * from @ProdChange

SELECT 
 old.ProductName,
 new.ProductName as FinalProductName
FROM
 @Prod as old
 INNER JOIN @ProdChange as link
  ON old.ProductID = link.FK_ProductID
 INNER JOIN @Prod as new
  ON new.ProductID = link.FK_FinalProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the responses, with the help Chad Zinks answer I came to the correct solution:

```
select
PRDHIST.Date,
OLDPROD.ProductName,
NEWPROD.ProductName
from dbo.Product_ChangeHistory PRDHIST
inner join dbo.Product_Detail OLDPROD
on OLDPROD.PK_ProductID = PRDHIST.FK_ProductID
inner join dbo.Product_Detail NEWPROD
on NEWPROD.PK_ProductID = PRDHIST.FK_FinalProductID;
```